# Увеличить массив на n раз

Tags: java, android

Всем привет.  Только недавно начать осваивать Java. 
В меня такой вопрос. Как увеличить массив строк?

Например, есть массив `String [] mas = {“a”,”b”, “c”,”d”}`,
и есть переменная `int i`, 
Надо в зависимости от i  увеличить массив.
Например, если i = 3, то массив должен увеличится на 3 массива mas и стать
`String [] mas1 = {“a”, ”b”, “c”, ”d”,  “a”, ”b”,  “c”, ”d”,  “a”, ”b”, “c”, ”d”}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого лучше использовать Динамические структуры.

Но если нужно то:

```
String[] mas1 = new String[mas.length*i];
for(int k=0; k < mas1.length; k+=mas.length){
   for(int j=0; j < mas.length; j++){
      mas1[j+k] = mas[j];
   }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Все работает.

Я пробовал через System.arraycopy
 но в меня нечего не получалось.

Answer (score 0):

Вот сделал через System.arraycopy.

> public static String []combineString1(String[] second, int i){
>
> ```
>   String [] arr = new String[second.length];
>   int j=0;
>
>  if (i==0)
>  {
>  System.out.println("Массив пустой");
>  return null;
>   }
>
>  String [] arr3 = new String[second.length * i];
>  System.arraycopy(second, 0, arr3, 0, second.length);   
>
>  for(int k=1; k<i; k++){          
>
>   if (i>j){
>   j++;
>
>       System.arraycopy(second, 0, arr3, arr.length, second.length);           
>       arr = new String[second.length + arr.length];
>
>   }
>
>  }
>  System.out.println("concatenated String array : " + Arrays.toString(arr3));
>  return arr3;
>               }
> ```

Строго не судите. Учусь.